# How to read source web site already open in browser

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I wondering to know if is any way to open url in browser and read source opened url ?
I'm trying to check if my XPath selector getting right value of captcha img src. I can't do this making 2 connections to url cause captcha will reload every single time i connect to url.

For reading source i'm using:

```
url = "https://prod.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG/CEIDG.Public.UI/Search.aspx"
sock = urllib.urlopen(url)
htmlSource = sock.read()                            
sock.close()
```

To open url in browser i'm using:

```
if sys.platform=='win32':
    os.startfile(url)
elif sys.platform=='darwin':
    subprocess.Popen(['open', url])
else:
    try:
        subprocess.Popen(['xdg-open', url])

    except OSError:
        print 'Please open a browser on: '+url
```

Does any of you guys know how to solve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the cross platform python GUI tool kits such as [wx.Python](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.html.HtmlWindow-class.html), pyside, etc., have a html display window that you can use to display the html source from within your python.  I would recommend using one of those to display your content from within your python code.

Comment: I will try wx.Python. Hope i will find some examples of use

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. To see url in browser and in the same time see source code of this page just use this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import etree, html

url = "https://prod.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG/CEIDG.Public.UI/Search.aspx"
adres_prefix = "https://prod.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG/CEIDG.Public.UI/"
adres_sufix = etree.XPath('string(//img[@class="captcha"]/@src)')

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
html_source = browser.page_source # i'm getting source code of open url

root = etree.HTML(html_source)
result = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, method="html")
result2 = adres_sufix(root)
www = adres_prefix + result2
print www # now i see if XPath gives me right value
```

Hope it will help others
Thanks anyway for any help

Answer (score 0):

You probably are going to need to make more than one request to get the CAPTCHA. Get yourself a copy of Fiddler 2 (free) http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler. It will allow you to see the "conversation" between the server and your browser. Once you see that, you will probably know what you need.

Comment: I don't need to make more than one request :)

Comment: Actually, if you inspect the content closely, you will find a whole slew of server requests that needed to be made. In particular this url, relative to the referer, "captcha.ashx?id=ac2ddb38-4675-43e1-96d0-717e6ff15e16&asmp3=1&t=" is the one that served the CAPTCHA to you. This was hidden from you by using the webdriver component of selenium and Firefox on your system - which took care of making all the requests necessary.